# Flex item exceeds

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flex layout to create a web IDE that looks like vscode.

The layout looks like this:

[image]

But if I have something very long inside of `content` area, the view will look like this:

[image]

I want to constraint the `content` and `others` area not exceed browser's right boundary.

Here is the sample code:

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#row1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

#row2 {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#row3 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  flex: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="row1">
    activitybar
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <div id="col1">
      content
      <pre>
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
      </pre>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">others</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<!-- I want view like this -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="row1">
    activitybar
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <div id="col1">
      content
    </div>
    <div id="col2">others</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is because you are using `pre` which will preserve whitespace. Is there any reason for this? The easiest way would be to allow the text to wrap by not using `pre`, perhaps a `div` instead.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes, I don't want to do word wrap, because this content will show some logs. I think is more readable not to wrap word.
Can I make <pre> `overflow-x: auto` based on the content area's width? 
I tried many times, but all test failed.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the `pre` tag *per se*. It has to do with the *minimum sizing algorithm* of flex items, which sets a default minimum width relative to the content width (i.e., `min-width: auto`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `pre` tag so text is displayed as it is in your code, so you need to break it using `white-space: normal`

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#row1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

#row2 {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#row3 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  flex: 0.5;
}

pre {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="row1">
    activitybar
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <div id="col1">
      content
      <pre>
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
      </pre>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">others</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Other option is to use `overflow: auto` on both `row` and `col` elements and this will create scroll-bar on parent of the `pre` element and keep `white-space`

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#row1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

#row2 {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#row3 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  flex: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="row1">
    activitybar
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <div id="col1">
      content
      <pre>
TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
      </pre>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">others</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to do word wrap, because this content will show some logs. I think is more readable not to wrap word. Can I make <pre> overflow-x: auto based on the content area's width? I tried many times, but all test failed.

Comment: @Charles Wei Yes you can, see updated answer.

Comment: It's really close to what I want. I more thing. Can I only overflow-x on <pre> tag? Not the whole content area. Because I want to put something above the <pre> tag to add some description. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can wrap it another div https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2179/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `white-space: pre-wrap` to wrap the text inside a `pre` element. In contrast to Nenad's answer, the benefit of `pre-wrap` is that it preserves the sequences of white-spaces, which is often the reason for using a `pre` element.

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#row1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

#row2 {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#row3 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

#col1 > pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  flex: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="row1">
    activitybar
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <div id="col1">
      content
      
      <pre>
TEST TEST TEST      TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
      </pre>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">others</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<!-- I want view like this -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="row1">
    activitybar
  </div>
  <div id="row2">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <div id="col1">
      content
    </div>
    <div id="col2">others</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't want to do word wrap, because this content will show some logs. I think is more readable not to wrap word. Can I make <pre> overflow-x: auto based on the content area's width? I tried many times, but all test failed.